# How to avoid trap representations when doing XOR bit-cancellation on signed ints?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, bitwise-xor, signed-integer

As as suggested solution for [Given three numbers, find the second greatest of them](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132990/9357), I wrote:

```
int second_largest(int a, int b, int c) {
    int smallest = min(min(a, b), c);
    int largest = max(max(a, b), c);

    /* Toss all three numbers into a bag, then exclude the
       minimum and the maximum */
    return a ^ b ^ c ^ smallest ^ largest;
}
```

The idea is that `^ smallest ^ largest` cancels out the bits such that the middle number remains.

However, @chux pointed out a problem:

> A singular problem with `int` and `a ^ b ^ c ^ smallest ^ largest` is that an intermediate result may be a trap representation on rare non-2's complement platforms. – chux
>
> @chux Please explain? XOR just operates bit by bit, and doesn't care what the bits represent, right? – 200_success
>
> XOR does not care, but the result maybe a problem: e.g. with say sign-magnitude integers, `-1 ^ 1` goes to `-0` which maybe a trap value - stopping the code. see C11 §6.2.6.2 2. Bit-wise ops are better used on unsigned types. – chux
>
> Further C11 §6.2.6.2 3 specifies implementation defined behavior for ^ with int on rare non-2's complement platforms . In particular "It is unspecified whether these cases actually generate a negative zero or a normal zero, " rendering a ^ b ^ c ^ smallest ^ largest unspecified that it will work as desired even if a trap value is not used. The next section explains how this can be UB. Best to leave this novel code to unsigned types. – chux

It seems unfortunate that a technique that should be logically and mathematically sound could be derailed by a technicality.

Is there a way to salvage this XOR technique and make it legally safe, ideally with zero runtime overhead?  (Something involving unions, maybe?)

Comment: Note this isn't unique to XOR - same argument could be applied to any bitwise operator.

Comment: You only need three comparisons to obtain the second largest out of three. How is that worse than the multiple comparisons done in the first two lines?

Comment: I would do three comparisons and encode the results into an index, then implement the logic as a 8-case switch.

Comment: "Is there a way to salvage this XOR technique" To me, the first question before this should be _Is there any reason to salvage this technique?_ ... and I'm not seeing one. As for "a technique that should be logically and mathematically sound", this assumes that (A) mathematics cares about bit representation, (B) the language standardises the representation used to store such values, and (C) both agree on this. None of these are true. Why not just use mathematical operators & do it right, rather than messing with bit-manipulation (which I _love_ but really doesn't seem relevant/useful for this)

Comment: @underscore_d Other than the trap representation issue, the only other requirement for this technique to work is that a collection of bits (e.g. `0x2545f28a`) means the same thing in `a`, `b`, `c` as it does in `smallest` or `largest`. It doesn't matter what the bits represent as long as it's consistent, so that the bits cancel out.

Comment: @underscore_d: Two's-complement addition and multiplication can be nicely mathematically defined in terms of abstract algebraic rings; the behavior of the other bitwise operators on members of those rings.  From a mathematical perspective, in an unbounded integer, -1 is an unbounded number of ones, and conversion of short integers to an unbounded integer represents extending the upper digit infinitely left.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to salvage this XOR technique and make it legally safe, ideally with zero runtime overhead

Use inline assembly. Assembly language is not bound by the rules of C/C++.

Maybe something like the following.

```c
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define min(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
#define max(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))

int second_largest(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int s = min(min(a, b), c);
    int l = max(max(a, b), c);

    int result;
    __asm volatile (
    "mov %1, %0    \n\t"
    "xor %2, %0    \n\t"
    "xor %3, %0    \n\t"
    "xor %4, %0    \n\t"
    "xor %5, %0    \n\t"
        : "=r"(result)
        : "g"(a), "g"(b), "g"(c), "g"(s), "g"(l)
    );

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = second_largest(10,20,30);
    printf("Result: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

The ***`r`*** machine constraint above means a register. The ***`g`*** machine constraint above means a register, a memory location or an immediate. Also see [Section 6.42.1 Simple Constraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html) of the GCC manual.

And then:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wstrict-overflow=5 test.c -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe 
Result: 20
```

Below is from `objdump --disassemble test.o` after compiling at `-O3`. It looks like overhead is kept to a minimum. It looks like bytes 0x00-0x17 perform the `min` and `max`; and it looks like the `xor` are performed at bytes 0x18-0x20.

```asm
0000000000000000 <second_largest>:
   0:   39 d7                   cmp    %edx,%edi
   2:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
   4:   89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
   6:   0f 4e c7                cmovle %edi,%eax
   9:   39 f0                   cmp    %esi,%eax
   b:   0f 4f c6                cmovg  %esi,%eax
   e:   39 d7                   cmp    %edx,%edi
  10:   0f 4d cf                cmovge %edi,%ecx
  13:   39 f1                   cmp    %esi,%ecx
  15:   0f 4c ce                cmovl  %esi,%ecx
  18:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  1a:   31 f0                   xor    %esi,%eax
  1c:   31 d0                   xor    %edx,%eax
  1e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  20:   31 c8                   xor    %ecx,%eax
  22:   c3                      retq
```

---

The downside to inline assembly is its not available everywhere. IA-32 code similar to above will work for BSDs, Linux, OS X, some Solaris and some Windows. For the hold-outs, like pre-Solaris Studio 12 or Visual Studio x64, you will need a function privded in an assembly source file assembled by the assembler and called from C/C++ code (i.e., a `*.S` or `*.asm` file).

Solaris Studio 12 [added support for GCC inline assembly](https://blogs.oracle.com/x86be/entry/gcc_style_asm_inlining_support), so earlier versions of Sun Studio require the assembler. Windows Win32 supports inline ASM in Intel syntax, but X64 requires you to use MASM because there's no inline assembly.

Comment: Interesting workaround. But X86 uses two's complement, so there wouldn't be trap representations anyway. Using X86 assembly as a workaround basically "solves" the problem by making the code non-portable.

Comment: @200_success - XOR, like AND, OR and NEG, is a bitop. It does not care whether you interpret the bit pattern as signed or unsigned. And yes, the code is non portable. We often have to use assembly language to work around C language short comings. A few additional examples of using assembly language to avoid C language short comings are checking for overflow, constant time operations, cache-sensitive operations, cpu feature detection and zeroizers. Its par for the course.

Comment: @200_success - For what its worth, I am here because I want to know what it means for: `a = 20; b = -40; a ^ b;`. I'm trying to discover what the resulting sign should be after normalizing to a sign/magnitude representation. Is it like NEG, where the bitop is only well defined for certain types or ranges? For example, `uint32_t a = 10; uint32_t b= -a` makes no sense for the datatype. Or do I need to normalize to a 2's compliment representation? Or do I need to restrict the range to positive numbers?